# Cisco C3750G Power On Failure

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-catalyst, power

I have been using my C3750G for a while now. It has been used normally and hasn't been exposed to any excess heat but for some reason when I issued the 'reload' command the other day the switch didn't start back up. Instead all of the indicator/status lights came on that are on the front, excluding the port link lights. Some were green and others orange. I left the switch for half an hour and the lights were still on. The switch wouldn't boot, and nothing on the serial.

Now, after this event to get the switch to boot, I have to plug into power and it will do the same thing and not boot. Other times it will boot properly. How can this be? I have upgraded the IOS on it today but it's no different. It is luck if the thing will boot or not. Sometimes this can be up to 10 times plugging into power and then disconnection and retrying.

Please can someone tell me what is wrong with my switch?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are experiencing an intermittent hardware failure. That would need to be fixed by Cisco, but you are more than four years beyond the last day of support for that switch model, so you are out of luck there.

It is time to replace the switch. It may soon fail completely, and you will not be able to get it to run at all.

Comment: I was really hoping this wouldn't be the case, thanks for your help.

Comment: Could be the dreaded bad memory issue, bad cpu issue, or given it's age, just a bad power supply. (they're cheap enough on ebay. or use this as an excuse to "upgrade")